# Bash, order of statements effecting string comparison, why?

Tags: bash

```
->[[ "abc~" == *~ ]]; echo $?; [[ *~ == "abc~" ]]; echo $?
0
1
```

In the above snippet why does comparison order seem to effect the truth values?

Comment: [Bash FAQ 34](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D_.24bar_.5D.5D_.28depending_on_intent.29)

Comment: do you mean =~ or == ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is only evaluated on the right side of the `==`. The second example evaluates the string `*~` literally.

This is the reason why quoting is required on the right hand side of an expression in double brackets, but no quoting is required on the left side.

```
[[ $a == "$b" ]] # Right

[[ "$a" == $b ]] # Wrong
```

Comment: And here is some more info about pattern matching http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob